# centos 6.5 upgrade uname gives different output

Tags: centos

I upgraded my CentOS machines from 6.4 to 6.5. My local machine, after the upgrade, gives this for

```
uname -r
2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64
```

My Linode show this -

```
uname -r
3.13.7-x86_64-linode38
```

The output is same for the following

```
more /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linode uses Xen for it's virtualization and for that to be supported it needs a different kernel.
They have their own kernel in the repos they provide to you by default.
So the version will be different from the "stock" CentOS kernel.
See: https://www.linode.com/kernels/

Comment: Unless of course you boot pvgrub.

Answer (score 1):

`uname -r` gives the output of the kernel-release, whereas the `/etc/redhat-release` file contains information about the distro's name and version.

Your scenario shows you have different kernel versions on your systems, but the OS release versions are the same.